# Rewriting a javascript "call" function using ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6

I have just seen a function written as followed:

```
function(callback, traversal) {
    traversal.call(this, callback);
};
```

Does this code mean calling the 2nd function `traversal` with the 1st function `callback` as the parameter and pass `this` as `this` object into `traversal` function call? Is this the old way of writing this kind of function? What is the ES6 way of writing it?

Comment: ES6 way to write this would be `traversal.call(this, callback);`.

Comment: Well, there's a certain amount of manipulation of `this` going on, but you'd probably want to see the wider scope of the code to tell whether you could more concisely write it with arrow functions etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe this code is extracted from a Tree implementation in javascript. I would like to see if it is possible to rewrite it using arrow function. But I guess maybe the author just want to have a more flexible implementation.

Comment: @newguy instead of talking about the code, paste it

Comment: Potentially related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)